# Call an alias in a case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I have this code that is to check each month to see if the person is enrolled in that month and at the end it is suppose to tell you if the person was enrolled for the whole year or not. The `Annual` is to check each month to see if they have a `1` from the case expression. The issue is I can't get SQL to recognize the alias names like `Jan` and `Feb`

```
Select SSN, FirstName, LastName,
  Case (DateEnrolled > '1-1-2019' and DateEnrolled < '1-31-2019' ) then 1 else 0 as [Jan],
  Case (DateEnrolled > '2-1-2019' and DateEnrolled < '2-28-2019') then 1 else 0 as [Feb],
  ...
  Case (Jan = 1 AND Feb = 1 AND...) then 1 else 0 as [Annual]
from EmployeePerson
```

Comment: There's no way this query as written will ever give you `1` for `Annual` as only one of `Jan` through `Dec` can possibly be `1` since their conditions are mutually exclusive. Note that your conditions don't include all of the days in the month either, you should have `>=` and `<=`, not `>` and `<`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
with cte as
(
Select SSN, FirstName, LastName,
  Case (DateEnrolled > '1-1-2019' and DateEnrolled < '1-31-2019' ) then 1 else 0 end as [Jan],
  Case (DateEnrolled > '2-1-2019' and DateEnrolled < '2-28-2019') then 1 else 0 end as [Feb],
  ...
from EmployeePerson
)

select SSN, FirstName, LastName, [Jan], [Feb]...,[Dec],
Case (Jan = 1 AND Feb = 1 AND...AND [Dec] = 1) then 1 else 0 end as [Annual]
from cte
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this !
SELECT SSN, FirstName, LastName,
  CASE WHEN (DateEnrolled > '01-01-2019' AND DateEnrolled < '01-31-2019')  THEN 'Jan',
  CASE WHEN (DateEnrolled > '02-01-2019' AND DateEnrolled < '02-28-2019') THEN 'Feb'
  END AS 'Annual'
FROM EmployeePerson;

I think it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select SSN, FirstName,
Case when Jan is null then 0 else 1 end as Jan,
Case when Feb is null then 0 else 1 end as Feb,
Case when Mar is null then 0 else 1 end as Mar,
Case when Apr is null then 0 else 1 end as Apr,
Case when May is null then 0 else 1 end as May,
Case when Jun is null then 0 else 1 end as Jun,
Case when Jul is null then 0 else 1 end as Jul,
Case when Aug is null then 0 else 1 end as Aug,
Case when Sep is null then 0 else 1 end as Sep,
Case when Oct is null then 0 else 1 end as Oct,
Case when Nov is null then 0 else 1 end as Nov,
Case when [Dec] is null then 0 else 1 end as [Dec],
Case when ([Jan] is not null AND [Feb] is not null AND [Mar] is not null AND 
    [Apr] is not null AND [May] is not null AND [Jun] is not null AND 
    [Jul] is not null AND [Aug] is not null AND [Sep] is not null AND 
    [Oct] is not null AND [Nov] is not null AND [Dec] is not null) then 1 else 0 end as Annual
from(
Select SSN, FirstName, format(DateEnrolled, 'MMM') Enrolled
from EmployeePerson)aa 
pivot (max(Enrolled) for Enrolled in([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])) as dtl
```